# Solving $2 \times 5^n - 1 = m^2$ in natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

This problem isn't of any particular importance in itself, but came up for me randomly, and though I couldn't crack it, I thought learning how would likely be instructive in improving my number theory skills.

Is it possible to completely classify the solutions to $2 \times 5^n - 1 = m^2$ in natural numbers (i.e., the values of $n$ for which the left-hand expression is indeed a square)? Those $n \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ clearly work, and after that most don't, but are these indeed all the solutions, and if so (or if whatever alternative holds), how does one see so?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124565/constructive-proof-need-to-know-the-solutions-of-the-equations

Comment: Ah, thank you for the links.

Comment: No problem; thank [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/). Also, let it be noted: this problem *does* have some importance in itself, because it is hard to solve, relates to factoring over Gaussian Integers, could help with related diophantine equations, and, most importantly, is a genuine mathematical inquiry, which are vital to discovering new mathematics

Comment: What you could try doing is considering a solution to $2\cdot 5^n=m^{2}+1$, proceed to factor both sides in terms of primes in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-1})$. Another user linked to this though so this should be ignored.

Comment: @Davehuff did you see the duplicate link?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I did not, I just looked at it now.